# Does Solana have additional aligment guarantees on `data` field of AccountInfo?

Tags: rust, validator, runtime

`data` field of Solana account is a byte slice, according to type system it is byte-aligned.
Does runtime internally use more strict alignment rules?
i.e. can I rely on the assumption, that `data` field has (for example) 8-bytes alignment?

```
// This code will trigger hard-fault, if data is not properly aligned
let num: u64 = unsafe {std::mem::transmute(data)};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VM guarantees that the provided account data is byte-aligned to a multiple of 8.

Fun fact: way back when, the first version of the BPF loader (now deprecated) did not do this alignment for you!

More information about program input format at https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/overview#input-parameter-serialization